# Set nginx proxy_pass scheme depending on whether upstream is local or remote

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, failover, proxypass

I wish to setup `nginx` as an https reverse proxy to a local application, failing over to remote hosts in case the local application is down, e.g. during deployment. My problem is I need the scheme (http or https) to depend on whether the upstream host is local or remote but I cannot find a way to set it dynamically.

Consider the below configuration.

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:8080; # scheme should be http here
    server a.example.com:443 backup; # scheme should be https here
    server b.example.com:443 backup; # scheme should be https here
}

server {
    listen   443;
    ...
    ...
    location / {
        # How can I set the proxy_pass scheme to https when upstream is a remote host?
        proxy_pass  http://backend;
    }
}
```

Is there a way of making the `proxy_pass` scheme depend on the chosen upstream? I looked into the `nginx` documentation and could not find any way of dynamically defining it. Am I missing something? Do I have to setup an intermediary server for localhost which handles https and set `proxy_pass https://backend`? That would be too bad.